# Three.js ShaderMaterial with lights on mesh imported from Blender

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to get a ShaderMaterial with lights working in three.js r77.  It works correctly when applied to a mesh with a simple BoxGeometry but it behaves incorrectly when applied to a mesh imported from Blender.

A simple jsfiddle illustrating the problem is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/5j0axcgz/).  The mesh on the left is created from a Blender export.  The mesh on the right is created from a simple BoxGeometry.  Both are using the same ShaderMaterial.  The position of the light is indicated by the DirectionalLightHelper.

The mesh on the right is being lit correctly, while the mesh on the left is not.  Clearly the problem is in my shader code.  I initially assumed that the problem is in the UV map on the imported mesh, but that does not appear to be true.  In the jsfiddle example the UV map is copied directly to the BoxGeometry mesh from the imported geometry---they're rotated relative to each other because of the coordinate differences between Blender and three.js, but the lighting is still working correctly on the mesh on the right with the imported UVs.

The shader code is:

```
THREE.TestShader = {
  uniforms: {
    "uDirLightPos": {
      type: "v3",
      value: new THREE.Vector3(20, 20, 20)
    },
    "uDirLightColor": {
      type: "c",
      value: new THREE.Color(0xffffff)
    },
    "uTexture": {
      type: "t",
      value: null
    },
  },
  vertexShader: [
    "varying vec3 vNormal;",
    "varying vec3 vViewPosition;",
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "void main() {",
    "vUv = uv;",
    "vNormal = normalize(normalMatrix * normal);",
    "vec4 mvPosition = modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);",
    "vViewPosition = -mvPosition.xyz;",
    "gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(position, 1.0);",
    "}"
  ].join("\n"),
  fragmentShader: [
    "uniform vec3 uDirLightPos;",
    "uniform vec3 uDirLightColor;",
    "varying vec2 vUv;",
    "varying vec3 vNormal;",
    "varying vec3 vViewPosition;",
    "varying vec4 mvPosition;",
    "uniform sampler2D uTexture;",

    "void main() {",
    "vec4 lDirection = viewMatrix * vec4(uDirLightPos, 0.0);",
    "vec3 lVector = normalize(lDirection.xyz);",
    "vec3 normal = normalize(vNormal);",
    "float diffuse = dot(normal, lVector);",
    "vec4 texel = texture2D( uTexture, vUv );",
    "gl_FragColor = vec4(uDirLightColor * diffuse, 1.0) * texel;",
    "}"
  ].join("\n")
};
```

In addition to a solution to this particular problem, a pointer to better documentation on the three.js shader stuff would be appreciated.  The official documentation for [ShaderChunk](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Renderers.Shaders/ShaderChunk), [ShaderLib](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Renderers.Shaders/ShaderLib), and [UniformsLib](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Renderers.Shaders/UniformsLib) is not what you'd call exhaustive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Blender-exported model has incorrect normals.

```
vnh1 = new THREE.VertexNormalsHelper( mesh1, 1, 0xff0000, 1 );
scene.add( vnh1 );
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5j0axcgz/1/

three.js r.77

Comment: Ah, it appears to be an issue with the three.js blender exporter---the normals are correct in blender.

Comment: Looks like it is the same issue, but it doesn't appear to be fixed in the exporter in master.

Comment: Hmm... https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/commit/bb0ff5d5856a3f226ff41edc5e58e7b14927a3dc If you believe there is still a three.js bug, a [bug report](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/.github/CONTRIBUTING.md). would be helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a bug or if it's just the exporter being very, very fragile---testing with several very simple models it's a crapshoot whether or not they work, despite all of them displaying correct normals in Blender.  What we really need is formal documentation/a checklist for the exporter documenting what it expects/needs to produce a righteous export.

Comment: If you would be willing to take on that task, I expect many users would be grateful. Please do not be too critical. There have been a lot of cooks in the kitchen.

Comment: I only wish I had the knowledge to do so.  Just now, for example, I discovered my notes for the ritual involved in getting a skeletal animation exported for r72 are now no longer correct for r77, so I've spent the afternoon trying to figure **that** out.  Part of the problem is that there's literally **no** official documentation, so web searches are the best documentation available.  But most search results are for old versions, and are therefore incorrect.  So figuring anything out ends up being a process of trial and error and source diving.